# Android - How to show rotated textview in Triangle

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPbak.png)

I use this xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_triangle_big_product"
                    android:visibility="@{viewModel.isBig == true ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:text="@string/big_discount"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
                        android:rotation="-45"
                        fontPath="fonts/bebasneue_regular.ttf"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneue_regular"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="-4dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

but the background triangle is fixed, when you rotate the text, the paddings are not adjusted according to the triangle. Text is sticking out on the first line.

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9b6W.png) [Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U913b.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
            android:rotation="45"/>
```

Rotation simple rotates your TextView and about designing it, up to you, either use drawable.xml or any other way you see fit

Comment: I know that. The background triangle is fixed, when you rotate the text, the paddings are not adjusted according to the triangle. Text is sticking out on the first line

Comment: I'll need a picture of what you are describing as I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Why don't you increase the size of the layout? Or just move the yellow background to cover bit more of the corner so the whole text can fit? Or decrease font size?